# jquery Navigation show and hide multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Being asked to make an SPA pizza place and running into issues with the show and hide feature. only the home page shows at all times

```html
 <nav>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" id="navHome" class="links" rel="Home">Sicilian Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu" id="navMenu" class="links" rel="Menu">Sicilian Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" id="navAbout" class="links" rel="About">Sicilian About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```html
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $("navHome").click(function (event) {
                $("home").show();
                $("menu", "about").hide();
            });
                $("navMenu").click(function (event) {
                    $("menu").show();
                    $("about", "home").hide();
                });
                $("navAbout").click(function (event) {
                    $("about").show();
                    $("home", "menu").hide();

                });
            }
```

Comment: If anyone could make a suggestion that would help, been sitting here for a little while and am sure it is something simple and in my face but have been looking at it for too long.

Comment: Your selectors are wrong, you should include the hash symbol. eg: #home, #menu, #about

Comment: Still only showing the home with that. Someone was telling me that it could be the document.ready and others have said it could be because there are inside each other and not on the same level...

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are incorrect. Base on your HTML you need to use id selectors:

```
$("#navHome").click(function (event) {
    $("#home").show();
    $("#menu, #about").hide();
});
$("#navMenu").click(function (event) {
    $("#menu").show();
    $("#about, #home").hide();
});
$("#navAbout").click(function (event) {
    $("#about").show();
    $("#home, #menu").hide();
});
```

Also there is a difference: `$("menu", "about")` means "find menu tag within about tag", while `$("#menu, #about")` means "find element with id menu and element with id about".

Comment: Thanks, yeah I changed the # after posting this but still only seeing the only the home div

Answer (score 0):

I copied your javascript and html to simulate the issue. I added alert statements in the functions to check if the click event is captured in the first place. But, the alert statements themselves were not coming up.

You need to make following two changes to your script to work:

1. prefix `#` with the ID's to capture the click event
2. a closing `)` is missing at the end of the script

Please find below the final script:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#navHome").click(function (event) {
            $("home").show();
            $("menu", "about").hide();
        });
        $("#navMenu").click(function (event) {
            $("menu").show();
            $("about", "home").hide();
        });
        $("#navAbout").click(function (event) {
            $("about").show();
            $("home", "menu").hide();
        });
    }
)
```